# Benchmarking many PostgreSQL queries

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.3

On a complex webpage more than hundred queries are executed. I search for a way to benchmark these queries. 
I tried to embed **EXPLAIN ANALYZE** into a query resp. into a psql function, to pick the execution time of every query and compare them.
But **EXPLAIN ANALYZE** seems not to be embeddable in any way.

Is there another solution to compare the execution time of some queries?

Thanks a lot

Comment: [Error Reporting and Logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) and [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) PS: "_On a complex webpage more than **hundred** queries are executed._" - for now I know why the web becomes slower and slower :o(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no problem with embedding `EXPLAIN` in PL/pgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION profile(
      IN query text,
      OUT total_cost double precision,
      OUT runtime double precision
   ) RETURNS record
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS
$$DECLARE
   j json;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, FORMAT JSON) ' || query INTO j;
   total_cost := (j->0->'Plan'->>'Total Cost')::double precision;
   runtime := (j->0->'Plan'->>'Actual Total Time')::double precision;
   RETURN;
END;$$;
```

You can use it for example as follows:

```
test=> SELECT * FROM profile($$SELECT * FROM large WHERE val = 'mama'$$);
┌────────────┬─────────┐
│ total_cost │ runtime │
├────────────┼─────────┤
│   14542.43 │ 207.836 │
└────────────┴─────────┘
(1 row)
```

Don't use it with untrusted queries, as the function is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need.

Comment: Would using the `Execution Time` instead of `Actual Total Time` be more accurate?

Comment: @Bergi I guess you are right. But the difference is usually marginal.