# How to check performance of psql queries

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, psql, query-performance

I know that I can get query execution time and planning time.

using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. but every time I run this it gives different time(execution and planning)

I know it depends on lots of factors like CPU load, memory usage, no off processes etc.
Can we tell PostgreSQL that execute the query `n` no. of times and give the average execution time?

something like:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
1000.time { 'select * from users' }
```

I know we can achieve this making request from some programming scripts on Postgres DB and record time on application end
EX: use ruby benchmark script:  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Let me know if anyone knows how to achieve this on Postgres terminal.
Thanks!

Comment: Use a solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40716581/6464308) and add a loop.

Comment: Use pg_bench and provide your SQL script as input?